# What's wrong with my date range in this SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm attempting to select data in a date range, but this is not working:

```
SELECT form_user.email
FROM form_instance JOIN
     form_user
     ON form_instance.form_user_id = form_user.form_user_id
WHERE form_instance.appointment_date >= '2017-04-13' AND <= '2017-05-11' AND
      form_instance.status = 3
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean.  The query looks fine.

Comment: the `where` clause should be `where form_instance.appointment_date >= '2017-04-13' AND form_instance.appointment_date <= '2017-05-11' AND ...`

Comment: You forgot to repeat the column name for `<=` case.

Answer (score 3):

this is the issue

```
 form_instance.appointment_date >= '2017-04-13' AND <= '2017-05-11'
```

this should be

```
 form_instance.appointment_date >= '2017-04-13' AND   form_instance.appointment_date <= '2017-05-11'
```

or use BETWEEN